# Filebeat doesn't send logs to logstack on ELK docker stack

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, containers, logstash, filebeat

I have ELK stack installed on dockers (each sits on different container, over the same network, and they use the official elk images).
This is how i configured the elk:

```
1. sudo docker network create somenetwork

2.
sudo docker pull elasticsearch:6.6.1 
sudo docker run -dit --name elasticsearch -h elasticsearch --net somenetwork -p 9200:9200 -p 9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:6.6.1

3.
sudo docker pull kibana:6.6.1
sudo docker run -dit --name kibana -h kibana --net somenetwork -p 5601:5601 kibana:6.6.1

4. RUN logstash
sudo docker pull logstash:6.6.1
sudo docker run -it --name logstash -h logstash --net somenetwork -p 5044:5044 -v $(pwd)/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline -v $(pwd)/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml logstash:6.6.1 logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
```

I also have app container that runs filebeat, which has "log.out" log file. this is the "filebeat.yml":

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /home/log.out
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["logstash:5044"]
```

the logstash configuration file, logstash.conf:

```
input
{
        beats {
                port => 5044
                host => "0.0.0.0"
        }
}

output{
        elasticsearch { hosts => ["elasticsearch:9200"] }
}
```

1. I can connect with telnet ($telnet logstash 5044), from the app container.
2. If I just use stdin from logstash (without getting the logs from filebeat), I can see the logs in Kibana.

I'm pretty sure I miss something simple. I'm new with elk. Thanks

Comment: can you share filebeat log?

Comment: where can i find filebeat logs?

Comment: In filebeat file under `<file beat inslation folder>\logs\`